# What to do if a colleague plans to submit the paper you worked on together without your name on it?

Tags: authorship, copyright

I have been working with another postdoc on a paper, here is what happened: I presented a work of mine before it was published (but it is in my thesis and on arxiv) and he decided he will use the same exact model with a slight change. I have talked it out with him and finally with my lab adviser as he was not collaborating, and we decided to send the paper as coauthors after our adviser mediated the issue (though it was bumpy), even sorted out whose name goes first etc.

The methodology belongs to me and the application area is the same (topic), although he has written all the code practically (he said he wanted to learn and build a more modular code etc) I did contribute by writing small scripts but he ended up not using them.

My advisor has asked their collaborating institute whether I could join (the irony that my methodology is stolen but I need a pass to join the project) and they did approve it (I have all exchanges and emails). I spent countless hours discussing and working on the project with him, as he is working on another project I have little clue about the execution but he had to travel often and he made a presentation to the partner institute. I also suspect that my adviser got the patent of the code on his name as I have noticed he took my name out of contacts on github recently. I had not asked to be in the copyrights of his code but he has told me that I was going to be there relating the model. My adviser only wants to please the partner institution I am afraid. I was away for a week and before that my colleague and I saw each other very briefly and all sounded to be on track. He has run over time for the completion of the project so he is not working here anymore technically. Today I get no reply from him on multiple attempts and I learnt that he has removed his computer's hard drive and my adviser is off for vacation for an unknown time.

I suspect that my colleague will try to send off the paper we were supposed to write together without my name on it, I have email exchanges as proof but most relied on my adviser, whom I don't know if I should trust after the copyright issue. What do I do if he sends the paper without my name? Do I write to the editors? His partner institution? Is there a board for this?

Comment: Without reading a wall of text - do some editing with paragraphs... But if they do submit then contact the editor with evidence that you contributed. Do keep all documentation, edits files etc

Comment: In the worst case maybe upload your version/results on arxiv.org and tell him you will do!? The editor is no judge nor Sherlock Holmes and maybe even a colleague/friend of your colleague...the questions here are often really funny :-)

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt I am not sure how this is supposed to be funny but glad to make you laugh. I have been a reviewer and an editor so it is not like I have delusions about them being superheroes.

Comment: Editor of a well known journal can take some measures, reject the paper, put the author in a black list, give a warning, do something. I was wondering if there is a consensus or a way to handle these issues, there should be.

Comment: I was forwarded a review by the editor of a journal, where my submission got major revision, then reject because I didn't revise it but resubmitted, and a person who was present at my thesis work presentation stole it and resubmitted as his own. The editor had found his way. Also I know cases where the person submitted was warned and their future submissions were probably not taken into consideration after that. Seriously there should be measures to discourage people from being so lax about stealing.

Comment: I just wouldn't know where he is submitting until it might be too late, and if the reviewers are not familiar with my work they might give it a pass. I also think maybe it is better to notify the partner institution, who would volunteer to be in this situation? It is discrediting. I just don't know. I can't put my version on arxiv cause it would be a similar attempt as his, besides I don't have final results.

Comment: It's more funny to me how some poeple aiming for a scientific career behave...lying, stealing...in the end this all comes out, science is finding the truth, with such behaviour you will never become a great scientist, but academia is no perfect world. My former comment is serious, maybe your only option is to publish the results on arxiv with him as co-author or never work again with him and learn from this. There "should be measures", well academia is a system of trust, not a judicial system. Setting up black lists etc. becomes complicated with so much alternative journals.

Comment: there is a reason scientists often only work together with colleagues they trust or in collaboratively funded official projects. My advise is to learn from this and move on. Sorry I have no better one, but I think there is none...

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt I did not chose to collaborate with him until he decided he will work on this project with an identical to a T( unpublished) method to mine ( right after I presented it in lab) without ever discussing it with me. Some people think if you write the code, it is not stealing sadly u.u So i had to compromise on sharing a paper and even that was difficult to sort it out because of my adviser's lax behavior towards him. He is in the same lab, one would think you won't have these problems. Anyway..

Answer (score 3):

> I have been working with another postdoc on a paper, here is what happened: I presented a work of mine before it was published (but it is in my thesis and on arxiv) and he decided he will use the same exact model with a slight change

There is a misunderstanding about "publishing": you probably mean that it was not published in a journal/conference, but apparently you did publish your model, which means two things:

- Your authorship on this is established
- Anybody can reuse it, provided they cite your work appropriately

> The methodology belongs to me

Not really: yes you are the established author of the methodology, but it is now available for anyone to reuse it, as per the usual academic process (the only exception would be if you patented the work prior to publication).

> I have talked it out with him and finally with my lab adviser as he was not collaborating, and we decided to send the paper as coauthors after our adviser mediated the issue (though it was bumpy), even sorted out whose name goes first etc.

This is what gives you a (moral) right to be a co-author for this particular work.

> My advisor has asked their collaborating institute whether I could join (the irony that my methodology is stolen but I need a pass to join the project) and they did approve it (I have all exchanges and emails)

Avoid using the word "steal" if you published it: if all that the other author did was reading your thesis/paper, the only requirement is for him to cite the origin of the work.

> I also suspect that my adviser got the patent of the code on his name as I have noticed he took my name out of contacts on github recently.

Are you talking about an actual patent? If yes, for what? If this is about your methodology which is already published or about a code publicly available on github (under a particular license maybe?), it's unlikely that a patent would be granted, but IANAL.

> Today I get no reply from him on multiple attempts and I learnt that he has removed his computer's hard drive and my adviser is off for vacation for an unknown time

Multiple attempts over how long? If it's only a few days there's no reason to panic, he might be busy. Did you agree on a method to write the paper together, a venue to submit it or a deadline?

> I suspect that my colleague will try to send off the paper we were supposed to write together without my name on it, I have email exchanges as proof but most relied on my adviser, whom I don't know if I should trust after the copyright issue. What do I do if he sends the paper without my name? Do I write to the editors? His partner institution? Is there a board for this?

You should rely primarily on your advisor, and if they don't cooperate you should seek support in your institution, e.g. head of department or ombudsman.

Comment: While I understand anyone in the world can read my thesis or arXiv paper, use my methodology and cite it, I do stand by my view in the case when a colleague from the lab decides to work on a paper with the same methodology, on the same problem, on the same dataset while they well know that you are in the process of trying to get it published (peer reviewed journal). The problematic part is us being in the same lab. How ethical is it to submit basically the same thing your colleague does while you know they are already in the process of submitting? And leaving them out on top?

Comment: And of course he has flaked out, or submitted by himself, I don't know, I have got a copy of the code , made changes, running tests, wrote and shared the paper so far but I will need his approval to submit. He did respond a few times after that/kind of buying time but he is no longer responsive (last 2 weeks). I can't reach the results on the cluster, errors in the code. Well he was not able to get a patent, but he tried without involving me. My PI says he won't contact him but I should. No idea where this is going.

Comment: well thanks for this part -> "You should rely primarily on your advisor, and if they don't cooperate you should seek support in your institution, e.g. head of department or ombudsman."  Though I am not sure if they would want to be involved.

Comment: Also, citing works on arXiv or citing peoples' thesis are not supervised, in principle you can get away with not citing these works as they are not peer reviewed publications. A person would have to sue you to prove their point. However, it is not ethical, so you don't just go around try to replicate arXiv papers and send them to journals.

Comment: @dusa given that this has become a conflict, it is important to find a mediator: normally it's your supervisor's role but you seem to suspect them as well. you're saying your head of department or ombudsman might not want to be involved: it's not a matter of whether they want or not, it's their responsibility. imho you shouldn't try to solve things by yourself. anyway even if you contact a publisher the first thing they will do is contact your institution to check your claim.

Comment: "The problematic part is us being in the same lab. How ethical is it to submit basically the same thing your colleague does while you know they are already in the process of submitting? And leaving them out on top?" It is certainly disrespectful and sloppy but it's not unethical as far as I know. why did you submit your paper on arXiv if you wanted to retain the exclusivity of the work?

Comment: "Also, citing works on arXiv or citing peoples' thesis are not supervised, in principle you can get away with not citing these works as they are not peer reviewed publications." You seem to misunderstand how this works: the fact that a publication is not peer-reviewed doesn't mean anybody can plagiarize it. An academic doing that would be at risk of being fired by their institution, whether the source is peer-reviewed or not.

Comment: " However, it is not ethical, so you don't just go around try to replicate arXiv papers and send them to journals". Normally a good journal should reject a publication which already exists on arXiv, unless the paper brings an additional new contribution.

Comment: Normally yes, ask me about this other story :) TLDR, I submitted a paper to the journal which returned as major revision then reject, about half a year later I was asked to review this paper which was majorly dependent on my work (without citing it), and it was submitted by a visitor of our lab who also happened to attend my presentation and follow me on researchgate.

Comment: I would like to give more credit but apart from the methodology, the keywords, phrases and key arguments were the same as well, and he clearly wrote it as if it were the first time this method was used. I contacted the editor and they made him cite it and edit the paper in a way that acknowledges previous work. I am really surprised that his institution didn't take further actions.

Comment: Because the editor passed my comment as is which was very clear about how it was close to a T. He works with a famous prof. too, some institutions/journals are lax, I suppose which wasn't the case at my PhD institution (as it should be)

Comment: So, I naturally get paranoid, if the editor didn't ask me to review I wouldn't know, and maybe he would get published because noone else pointed that out. It was a tier 2 journal btw, it is considered credible despite not being tier 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94178/discussion-between-erwan-and-dusa).

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here, one is that your "colleague" is engaging in plagiarism. This is a big no-no for most if not all journals. Just being accused of plagiarism can end someones academic career. As such, I am surprised anyone would do this so blatantly. If you know which journal the submission might go to, I would contact the editor in chief there and talk to him. With the method being in your thesis and on arxiv, you have a very good starting point in proving that the method belongs to you and the other guy is just a leech. (There are ways around this by properly attributing, but I doubt he does that)

The second issue is one of copyright. If you worked on code and wrote part of it, then your advisor has no right to remove your name. That's tantamount to stealing. And there are some nice fines for that, including jail time in severe cases. I would talk to your advisor about this, explain that it's not ok to remove your name. After that discussion, you should put it into writing and send it to him **on paper**, so he cannot refute anything later.

If your advisor or colleague are not cooperating in this, I strongly suggest to contact your universities legal department. Most universities do not like their students work being stolen, not even by their own professors.